# Celery Beat: Synchronizing schedule is the last debug message I see

Tags: python, celery, apache-superset, celerybeat

I am running superset and celery on AWS ECS. Celery worker, Celery beat and Superset are running in separate containers of the same task. I have turned on debug logs in celery so that I can see each step celery is taking. Celery *is* starting up and running. Celery worker goes until the log message `DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection`, celery beat goes until the first time it wakes up, then it displays the log message `DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...` and doesn't wake up again.

The command I am using to start the celery worker is:
  `celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app worker -E --pool=gevent -c 500 -l DEBUG`

The command I am using to start the celery beat is:
  `celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app beat --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid --schedule /tmp/celerybeat-schedule -l DEBUG`

From my superset_config.py, the relevant lines of code are:

```
class CeleryConfig:
    broker_url = "redis://%s:%s/0" % (REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)
    imports = (
        "superset.sql_lab",
        "superset.tasks",
        "superset.tasks.thumbnails",
    )
    result_backend = "redis://%s:%s/0" % (REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT)
    worker_log_level = "DEBUG"
    worker_prefetch_multiplier = 10
    task_acks_late = True
    task_annotations = {
        "sql_lab.get_sql_results": {
            "rate_limit": "100/s",
        },
        "email_reports.send": {
            "rate_limit": "1/s",
            "time_limit": 600,
            "soft_time_limit": 600,
            "ignore_result": True,
        },
    }
    beat_schedule = {
        "alerts.schedule_check": {
            "task": "alerts.schedule_check",
            "schedule": crontab(minute="*", hour="*"),
        },
        "reports.scheduler": {
            "task": "reports.scheduler",
            "schedule": crontab(minute="*", hour="*"),
        },
        "reports.prune_log": {
            "task": "reports.prune_log",
            "schedule": crontab(minute=0, hour=0),
        },
    }

CELERY_CONFIG = CeleryConfig

WEBDRIVER_BASEURL = "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
```

Things I have tried:

- Configuring a postgres database for Celery
- putting celery into the same container as superset
- Changed db numer in superset config
- Tried variations on WEBDRIVER_BASEURL (localhost:8088, [www.actual-url.com](http://www.actual-url.com))
- Changing the dependencies in the ECS task definition
- reconfiguring security groups for redis
- Various commands for starting celery worker and beat
- Ensuring the security group for the container allows ingress on port 6379
- I setup flower to run on the ECS instance; flower shows no workers, tasks or monitors

Things I know:

- Celery *is* connecting to Redis. (At one point it wasn't, and that threw very specific errors.)
- Celery *is* reading the schedule, I can see in the logs where it is displaying the three things scheduled for the beat_schedule.
- Schedule reports are not firing; there are no logs at the time of the report, nor is there evidence of a report being generated.
- I get an error `cron_descriptor.GetText:Failed to find locale en_US`, when I access the reports page of Superset (although, TBH, I feel like this is unrelated).

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I was using MemoryDb instead of Elasticache, and the two things are not interchangeable.